# How to call a function when launching an application

Tags: flutter, function, dart, class

I need to call a function when the application starts. I call it from the Main file, the function itself is in another file. I tried to do this, but there are no expected changes and the function in another file is highlighted with the warning

> Null numberColumnFunction() The declaration 'numberColumnFunction'
> isn't referenced. Try removing the declaration of
> 'numberColumnFunction'.

What 's wrong with my call ?

My Main:

```
void main() async{
 await ColumnView.numberColumnFunction();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

My fuction in class ColumnView:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    int numberColumn = 3;
    int columnsPositioned = 5;
    var visibilityColumn = false;

    numberColumnFunction(){
      if (numberColumn == 3) {
        columnsPositioned = 8;
        visibilityColumn = true;
      }
      else {
        () {
          null;
      };
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you made `numberColumnFunction` a function local to the `build` method.  It is not method on the `ColumnView` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a regular class like this and not use StatelessWidget or StatefulWidget class for calling only functions.

```
class ColumnView {
    int numberColumn = 3;
    int columnsPositioned = 5;
    var visibilityColumn = false;

    numberColumnFunction(){
    if (numberColumn == 3) {
        columnsPositioned = 8;
        visibilityColumn = true;
    }
    else {
        () {
            null;
           };
       }
    }
}
```

then call like that...

```
void main() async{
    await ColumnView().numberColumnFunction();
    runApp(const MyApp());
}
```